# When JSON data posted in rails throws param is missing or the value is empty: stall

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I have been trying post JSON data via POSTMAN but I get "param is missing or the value is empty: stall". Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
 def create 
  @stall = Stall.new(stall_params)

       if @stall.save
         render json: @stall, status: :created
       else
           render json: @stall.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end 
 end



private
def stall_params
  params.require(:stall).permit(:name, :place)
end
```

My Table contains only two columns name and place

Below is the log

```
Processing by API::V1::StallsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"trill", "place"=>"trill"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: stall):
  app/controllers/api/v1/stalls_controller.rb:47:in `stall_params'
  app/controllers/api/v1/stalls_controller.rb:27:in `create'


  Rendered /home/goutham/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (7.4ms)
  Rendered /home/goutham/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (16.0ms)
  Rendered /home/goutham/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /home/goutham/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (135.0ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `stall_params` method searches for params in the `'stall'` namespace.

Your JSON parameters must have to following format:

```
'stall': {
  'name': 'trill',
  'place': 'trill'
}
```

If you want the parameters in the top namespace, you have to remove the `#require` call in `stall_params`.

```
params.permit(:name, :place)
```